# Validate with asyncData/fetch - Commit data from within Validate?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

If I want to validate the existence of a dynamic resource Nuxt [recommends](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#validate-route-params) implementing a `validate()` call within the page component. If that call performs an API request for data in order to validate the existence of the resource, Nuxt documentation [states](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-validate) that I can check the Vuex store, but does not explicitly state that I can `dispatch` an action in order to `commit` data received by the API request. **The `store` within the `validate()` method allows calls to `dispatch` and syncs with the Vuex store just as with `asyncData` or `fetch`, but would this be an anti-pattern - committing data to Vuex from within `validate()`?**

> You can also check some data in your store for example (filled by nuxtServerInit before action

The need to `commit` data from within `validate()` will prevent a duplicate API call within `asyncData` or `fetch` to the same resource. As an example,
If I call `validate()` requesting the existence of a resource and I do not `commit` that resource's data to Vuex, I may need to request that resource data again from with `asyncData` or `fetch`.

```
validate ({ app, params, store }) {
  return app.$axios.get('client/cards', {params: { slug: params.card }})
    .then(() => true)
    .catch(() => false)
}
```

Essentially duplicating the same API request, but from within the action:

```
async fetch ({ params, store }) {
  await store.dispatch('card/getCard', params.card)
}
```

Comment: upvoted! for visibility this is my question too